# Excel VBA Listbox use of SelectedIndexChanged event

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, selectedindexchanged

I am trying to utilize the Excel VBA Listbox SelectedIndexChanged event to update a textbox on the same userform with the sum of the values in one column of my listbox as the user selects each row in that listbox.

I can not figure out how to get the code for that event handler to execute.  Any suggestions?  I am using Excel VBA with the latest version of excel from office 365 on a windows 10 machine. In fact i don't even see that event listed in the pulldown when i have the code window up for that userform?

Thanks
Mike

Comment: Never mind - I just used the change event and it works just fine

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
  // Your can do anything with it

  // Looping here
     For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
       If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
        ListBox1.Selected(i) = False
       End If
     Next
  End Sub
```

Comment: This works fine for small Listboxes, but is quite slow for large ones.